# .htaccess rewrite for subdomain only

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have the following .htaccess code that successfully rewrites subdomain directories. So if a user visits `jim.domain.com` they get served `placeholder.php?page_type=profile`. However, this also affects the main directory `http://domain.com`. I'd like it so that anything with a subdomain is directed to the placeholder.php page, but using the main directory with no subdomain would act as usual, going to the `index.php` in the main directory. How would I achieve this? Thanks for any advice.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^exclude.domain.(.*)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.(.*)

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)\.domain\.com

RewriteRule ^$ placeholder.php?page_type=profile [L,QSA]
```

Comment: You are mixing terminology a bit - "main directory" - do you mean to say "main domain"? And you have exclusion rules for `www.domain.tld, exclude.domain.tld` Should those remain in place?

Comment: Hi Michael - I have no doubt that I'm mixing my terminology up... trying to get my head around all this ;). Basically what I want is this. www.domain.com acts as it should by default displaying index.php. And anything with a subdomain, anything.domain.com should go to domain.com/placeholder.php?page_type=profile

Comment: Do your existing rules not already do that? (except for `exclude.domain.tld` which also goes to index.php)  The `RewriteCond !^www\.domain\.(.*)` should properly exclude it from placeholder.php (note the backslashes to escape `.`, however)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your wanting all requests for `test.domain.com` to go to `domain.com/placeholder.php?page_type=profile` as in your comment then you need to include the domain in the rewrite

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^exclude.domain.(.*)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.(.*)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^$ http://domain.com/placeholder.php?page_type=profile [L,QSA]
```

this will not how ever deal with this part

> but using the main directory with no subdomain would act as usual, going to the index.php in the main directory

because you have no file/directory miss rules that redirect to index.php. Do you need those, or really just want to solve the first part?

I also wonder if your wanting `profile` replaced with the subdomain match, in which case you want

```
RewriteRule ^$ http://domain.com/placeholder.php?page_type=%1[L,QSA]
```

but both of these examples will not rewrite any path of `test.domain.com/longer_url` because the `^$` is only matching an empty URL path. But how you want to handling paths needs to be decided before a suitable Reerite can be proposed.

Comment: Hi Simeon - thanks for your help. Im trying to follow your examples, but without much luck so far. As I mentioned in my comment above - Basically speaking, what I want is this... www.domain.com acts as it should by default displaying the index.php (this is how it acts without any rewrites). And then any URL starting with a subdomain, like anything.domain.com should go to http://domain.com/placeholder.php?page_type=profile, but still show anything.domain.com in the address bar. Does that make sense? Sorry for any confusion, I'm still learning this ;)

Comment: @Chris So what "no luck" are you having with my examples, as I cannot read you mind.